# Getting the first & last name of a user using Sign in with Apple (OAuth 2.0)?

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, oauth

I need to fetch the first & last name of the user. But according to the docs this info is only passed in the authorization phase if you define a scope like this: `scope: "email name"`.The problem is that Apple enforces me to use `response_mode: "form_post"`, this is required if you want to request the name of the user.

After some research, I've learned that this form_post response mode means that a http post request is done by apple on the redirect uri, with the first & last name as form data. My app is written in ionic and I don't understand how this should be implemented.

Ideally i retrieve the user's first & last name in my frontend and i send it along with the authcode to my backend to retrieve an idtoken and identify the user, but is this even be possible if i have to use `form_post` response mode?

I've thought about setting my redirect uri to the uri of my backend, but then how would my frontend (ionic app) know that the user has successfully been authenticated and get an access token?

```
get appleLoginUrl() {
    this.state = uuidv4();
    const url = APPLE_API_BASE_URL + "/auth/authorize"
    const queryParams = {
      client_id: environment.apple.client_id,
      redirect_uri: AUTH_REDIRECT_URL,
      state: this.state,
      response_type: "code",
      response_mode: "form_post",
      scope: "email name"
    };
    const queryString = this.buildQueryString(queryParams);
    return `${url}${queryString}`;
  }

  loginApple(code: string, state: string) {
    if (code && this.state == state) {
      const url = MY_API_URL + this.URL_PATH_APPLE
      const headers = this.getAuthHeader(code);
      this.httpClient.post(url, null, { headers })
    }
  }
```

Comment: What you can do is, set the redirect URL as your backend URL and once backend processes the data received from Apple (assuming storing it in some db), you can send a redirect response to your frontend URL.

Comment: But in this case, Apple is the one that invokes a REST call on my backend, not my frontend, so there's no way to "respond" to my frontend. There's no such thing as a frontend URL, my frontend = ios and android mobile apps built with ionic

Comment: As per their documentation, for web applications, you should use [Sign in with Apple JS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js) instead of the REST API one.